# Button listener to create incremented title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a form for my website which would let users add step by step 
tutorials. Each time a user clicks on 'add a step' , a new Block with an image field and a text field appears.

I'm beginning with jQuery and I wanted to have a title displayed before every new block appearing after the user's click which would be 'step 1' ... 'step n'

I tried adding an HTML field to the block and filling it like this (263 is the ID of the 'add a step' button and 323 of the HTLM Field I added):

```
$x = 0
$([263]).click(function () {
$x ++ ;
$("[323]").val("Step $x");
}
```

But it doesn't work ... Could anyone help me please ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post all of the JavaScript and HTML, otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: i made a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/uh8m2wax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ID selector from jQuery `#...` and you where missing the close `);` for the click function. and finally `.text()` is used to set H1 title:

```
var x = 0
$("#323").text("Step " + x);
$("#263").click(function() {
    x++ ;
    $("#323").text("Step " + x);
});
```

and don't use `$x` looks like php world :)

you can fiddle around with the code here http://jsfiddle.net/uh8m2wax/

you can place the code at the end of your page prior to the body tag like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var x = 0
     $("#323").val("");
     $("#263").click(function() {
        x++;
        $("#323").val("Step " + x);
     });
});//]]> 
</script>
</body>
```

**EDIT**: changed from `.text()`to `.val()` since input box is used for display

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Do I have to add at the beginning :             <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){                                                                                         and </script> at the end ?

Comment: made a copy-paste sample for lazy people ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I modified a little bit the code to have a text box and not a header but when I add what I wrote above there is a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/uh8m2wax/2/ but it works without the <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$( document ).ready(function() { and </script>

Comment: in fiddle you don't need script tag. It is added automatically there. you only need that for copy past in your actual page

Comment: here the fiddler way: https://jsfiddle.net/uh8m2wax/4/ - updated my copy paste sample with `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$x = 0;
$([263]).click(function () {
   $x ++ ;
   $("[323]").val("Step " + $x);
}
```

Comment: `$([263])` is not a jQuery container of nodes. It's a container for a number which obviously doesn't have a `click` function. Why do you copy OP wrong code?